# No Activity found when navigating to another activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

btnAdd is supposed to open the SecondActivity where it gathers a new email          address and return it to the first Activity and stores in the array.  It will        then add the new email address to display in the ListView.
Also, every time i open the app, it keeps appending to the list, if i start   with 4 email addresses, every time i run app, it adds to it giving me this error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 

DBAdapter db;    
ListView listContacts;    
Button btnAdd;    
int selectedItem = 0;    
String name, email;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listContacts);
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       // Start 2nd Activity
       startActivity(new Intent("ca.nbcc.lizgoldston.SecondActivity"));
       finish();
       if(selectedItem != 0){
                insertContact(name, email);
            }
        }
    });

    db = new DBAdapter(this);   // Set up our DBHelper
        addContacts();              // Add some generic data to DB for   display purposes
    listContacts();             // Display the records in a ListView

    // Set the Listener on the ListView and change background color for selected item
    listContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listContacts.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            listContacts.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // Get the ListItem at position clicked
            listContacts.setSelection(position);
            listContacts.setSelected(true);
            String info = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); // Get the String with contact info
            int contactId = Integer.parseInt(info.substring(0,info.indexOf(":"))); // Parse for contact id
            selectedItem = contactId;  // Set the selectedItem id
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void addContacts() {
    // Add some generic contact records for display purposes
    db.open();
    if (db.insertContact("Sally Brown", "sally@nbcc.ca") >= 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (db.insertContact("John Smith", "john@nbcc.ca") >= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (db.insertContact("Tom Brown", "tom@nbcc.ca") >= 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (db.insertContact("Susie Brawn", "susie@nbcc.ca") >= 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    db.close();
}

public void getContacts() {
    // Get all contacts
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    if (c.moveToFirst())  // As long as there are records
    {
        do {
            displayContact(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}

public Contact getContact(int _id) {
    // Get a contact based on id provided
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getContact(_id);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){  // As long as there are records
        displayContact(c);  // Display the specific contact
        contact.setId(c.getInt(0));
        contact.setName(c.getString(1));
        contact.setEmail(c.getString(2));
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.close();

    return contact;
}

// Method to update a contact with the info provided
public void updateContact(int _id, String _name, String _email) {
    // Update contact
    // This could obviously be made 'prettier' by adding confirmation dialog, etc.
    db.open();
    if (db.updateContact(_id, _name, _email)) {
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.close();
}

// Method to delete contact with the id provided
public void insertContact(String name, String email) {
    // Add Contact
    db.open();
    if (db.insertContact(name, email) == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.close();
}

public void displayContact(Cursor c)
{
    // Display specific Contact in the cursor provided
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "id: " + c.getInt(0) + "\n" +
                    "Name: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Email:  " + c.getString(2),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void listContacts(){
    // Show the database contacts in a ListView
    List<String> contactList = getContactList();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);
    listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public List<String> getContactList(){
    List<String> contactList = new ArrayList<String>();
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            contactList.add(c.getString(0) + ":" + c.getString(1) + ":" + c.getString(2));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return contactList;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {  

TextView txtEmail;        
EditText txtAddress;        
Button btnSave;        

@Override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);

    txtEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == findViewById(R.id.btnSave)) {
                MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
                main.email = txtAddress.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_email, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();    
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter {  

static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";    
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";    
static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";    
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";    

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";    
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";    
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;    

static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE contacts (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "name text not null, email text not null);";


final Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context _context){
    this.context = _context;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ". This will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Downgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ". This will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// Open the db
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Closes the db
public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}

// Insert a new contact
public long insertContact(String name, String email){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Deletes a specific contact
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId){
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// Getting All Contacts in a List
public List<Contact> getAllContactsList() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Retrieve all contacts
public Cursor getAllContacts(){
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Retrieve a specific contact
public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

// Update a contact
public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name,
         String email){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {    

private int id;        
private String name;        
private String email;    

public int getId() {    
    return id;    
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout  

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"   
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"   
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
tools:context=".MainActivity"    
android:orientation="vertical">    

<TextView
    android:text="Email Addresses..."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"  />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContacts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listContacts"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_secondactivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout  

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"    
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
tools:context="ca.nbcc.lizgoldston.emaillistapp.email"    
android:orientation="vertical"    
android:clickable="true">    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:text="Add a new email... "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="enter a new email here"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="SAVE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
   // Start 2nd Activity

   if(selectedItem != 0){
            insertContact(name, email);
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        finish()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats perfect. It worked !!!  Can i ask a question?  Every time i go into app, it adds the same data and appends to the database. How can i fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by "i go into app" ?? is it you navigate from first activity to second ??

Comment: When i run the app from Android Studio, it takes the data to be listed and adds to what was there before. The list doesn't clear when i exit the app

Comment: if you need to empty the list, you can do it as like this listContacts.setAdapter(adapter);   ,  put this in the onPause() method.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJhon. You have been a great help